# App center failed to distribute Android react-native version

Tags: android, react-native, appcenter

I´ve run the build and its successufuly but I cant distribute I'm getting this error:

Oh no! Build 37 failed to distribute. Error: No release found for appId: aa62c74d-d63f-4d0c-8560-632eb8671be8, principalId: 4f7bf3fe-f2c8-4e40-81f4-33adf575a2dd

[image]

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is the AppId correct?

Comment: yes it´s, i suppose this was a internal problem with appCenter, because is working now and I didn't changed nothing.